# What does this code means?

Tags: c#

```
namespace myApplication    {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

What is `partial class Form1 : Form`

and what is `InitializeComponents();`

and why it is used `Form1 : Form` instead of only `Form1`

Comment: Try removing each of those three things in turn, and looking at the compiler error messages and any changes in behaviour. Then you'll get a hint at what they are for. You can also try googling "partial classes c#", "InitializeComponent WinForms" and "c# inheritance".

Comment: You should probably get hold of a good beginners guide to C#. Here is one called Introduction to the C# Programming Language which might be useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/beginner/bb308730.aspx

Comment: I have did that and googled this but i didn't able to understand.....Thanks for reply

Comment: +1 from me. one of the very basic things and most of us are not aware of it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`InitializeComponents();` is a function for initializing the values of the form. Please right click on it and click on Showdefinition to see its contents. It is used to assign values to labels, textbox, Buttons etc in your form.

`public partial class Form1 : Form`
 By using `partial` it is possible to write the definition of same class in two different source file in the same namespace.It will be treated as same during compilation.You can find a class with same name `Form1` in your project which is created automatically.

Form1 is the name of the Form and `:` is used to inherit the properties of base class . Here `Form` represents `System.Windows.Forms.Form`. We are inheriting to access the properties and methods of base class.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at `partial class Form1 : Form` - obviously this is declaring a `class` called `Form1`. The `: Form` part means that it **inherits** from the base class `Form`.

The base `Form` class provides lots of functionality needed by all forms - including `InitializeComponents()` (more on which below).

The **`partial`** keyword means that this class is only partly defined in this source file, and the compiler must look elsewhere for the remainder of the definition (in this case it will be some automatically generated code which defines amongst others all the controls you placed on your form in the designer).

`InitializeComponents()` is a required call in all subclasses of `Form` and it instructs all the components on the form to initialise, position, and display themselves as appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

1. Class declaration
2. Method call
3. Inheritance

But asking questions like this is no good.

Comment: Why is this answer being voted up? Its incredibly unhelpful...

Comment: Thanks for ur kind reply and i will try to ask good questions. again Thanks

Comment: This answer adds absolutely no value.

Comment: Two wrongs don't make a right.